# Llive clock function in AngularJs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want display Hours,Minutes ans seconds(live), I written function using `$interval` in controller but `$scope` not updating my view.

here is **my view :**

```
<div ng-controller="clockCtrl">
{{hour}}:{{min}}:{{sec}}
</div>
```

here is **my Controller :**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('clockCtrl',function($scope,$interval){


 $interval(callAtInterval, 1000);
});


    function callAtInterval(){
          console.log("this text is getting printed after each second");
          var today = new Date();
          h=today.getHours();
          var m = today.getMinutes();
          var s = today.getSeconds();
          $scope.hour=h;
          $scope.min=m;
          $scope.sec=s;


    }
```

The function is getting call but view is not getting updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `callAtInterval` function is declared outside of the controller, thus it doesn't have access to `$scope`. You should declare it like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('clockCtrl',function($scope,$interval){

    function callAtInterval(){
        console.log("this text is getting printed after each second");
        var today = new Date();
        h=today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        $scope.hour=h;
        $scope.minutes=m;
        $scope.sec=s;
    }

    $interval(callAtInterval, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I did this its working Fine..Thanks Mike..Happy Coding